# jQuery Tools Scrollable on touch disable vertical scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, scrollable, jquery-scrollable

I have a similiar slider to the one on [jquerytools.org](http://jquerytools.org)

But how do I disable vertical touch events on the slider? This is quite a problem when the slider on portrait mode takes up nearly the whole screen estate.

I tried

```
$("#flowpanes").scrollable({ circular: true, easing: 'swing', vertical: false })
```

but that doesn’t work.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Ok, so there’s an official git issue:
https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issues/711

Comment: This helped me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940351/jquery-tools-touch-horizontal-only-disable-vertical-touch/16540246#16540246