# Jquery Tools Touch horizontal only disable vertical touch

Tags: jquery, scroll, touch, gesture, swipe

I have jquery tools scroller... I like it to have touch option implemented for swipeLeft swipeRight only.

When I use touch: true, it does rotates when swipeUp/Down as well..

I followed instructions here:

> [jQuery Tools Scrollable on touch disable vertical scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836802/jquery-tools-scrollable-on-touch-disable-vertical-scroll)

and here:

> http://awardwinningfjords.com/2010/09/22/handling-touch-events-in-jquery-tools-scrollable.html

but none seem to work.. any ideas? my Fiddle/demo is below for reference

> fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mmp2m/7/
>
> demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mmp2m/7/show

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the only control you are using is **Scrollable** then you could edit the source code for it from [here](https://raw.github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/master/src/scrollable/scrollable.js) to fix that behaviour or adapt it as you see fit.

I modified the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmp2m/16/) you had posted to include the code for the **Scrollable** control in the `JavaScript` code section.

The lines added in the code for the control are the ones with the comment `// added` at the end in the following snippet:

```
    // touch event
    if (conf.touch) {
        var touch = {};

        itemWrap[0].ontouchstart = function(e) {
            var t = e.touches[0];
            touch.x = t.clientX;
            touch.y = t.clientY;
        };

        itemWrap[0].ontouchmove = function(e) {

            // only deal with one finger
            if (e.touches.length == 1 && !itemWrap.is(":animated")) {            
                var t = e.touches[0],
                     deltaX = touch.x - t.clientX,
                     deltaY = touch.y - t.clientY,
                     absX = Math.abs(deltaX),                              // added
                     absY = Math.abs(deltaY);                              // added

                // Only consider the event when the delta in the
                // desired axis is greater than the one in the other.
                if(vertical && absY > absX || !vertical && absX > absY)    // added
                    self[vertical && deltaY > 0 || !vertical && deltaX > 0 ? 'next' : 'prev']();

                e.preventDefault();
            }
        };
    }
```

I've tried this in Android with the native and Opera browsers and seems to work as expected.

Comment: I tried to modify the code but without luck... I set the `deltaY = 0`  and ` vertical && deltaY > 0 ||` but didn't work... but ur solution work :) can u tell me what || and ? Mean?

Comment: The `?` is used to express an inline `if` statement, its structure is `boolean-expr ? then-expr : else-expr;`. The `||` is just the logical `or` operator that's being used in the `boolean-expr` of the inline `if` statement.

For more information on the `?` operator check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270351/how-to-write-a-inline-if-statement-in-javascript

Comment: Had a slight bug where it e.preventDefault(); prevented the scrolling down the page when swiped... fixed version is here http://jsfiddle.net/shavindra/nvyU8/4/

Comment: This worked beautifully after making one change. The e.preventDefault should be part of the if statement, otherwise the vertical scroll doesn't scroll the page.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue for a while until I found the following fix-

Initialization-

```
var $scroller1 = $('#outer-container1').kinetic({'y':false});
```

This prevents vertical scroll on the container but does not hand the vertical scroll to the browser scroller.

Then go to the jquery kinetic source code and comment out the `e.preventDefault()` for all mouse and scroll action events.

This hack worked for me.
https://github.com/davetayls/jquery.kinetic/issues/33