# How to disable horizontal scrolling on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, css

I have a web app written in html5 with css3 that works find on iPad and android. Problem is, on iPhones, the whole page seems be scrolled sideways when I pull it. (Only happens on iPhones).
**it's not a scroll bar problem**, since horizonly - the body element is 100% the screen width. so overflow is not the way to go here.
could any one help please?

Comment: can you link html and css or screen shot

Comment: Have you tried debugging using Safari, you can see and experiment to find the error

Comment: yes, i was. mostly iphone 4 u face problems

Answer (score 0):

this might help,add these metas to your code :

```
<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />
<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
```

Comment: Thank you Mayank, that helped me to disable zooming which was yet another problem i was facing. But the side scrolling is still there...
it's not exactly scrolling.. more like draggind of the page to the side...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885625/prevent-horizontal-scroll-in-ios-webapp OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890361/disable-scrolling-in-an-iphone-web-application...these questions might help.... :)