# Disable scroll down with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Is there any way to disable only scroll down in jQuery?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: try $(document).scroll(function(){ return false;});

Comment: Try this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940351/jquery-tools-touch-horizontal-only-disable-vertical-touch

Comment: I only want to disable the down scrolling, not the up scrolling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('html, body').bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel MozMousePixelScroll', function(e) {
    var scrollTo = 0;

  if (e.type == 'mousewheel') {
      scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);
  }
  else if (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll') {
      // scrollTo = 20 * e.originalEvent.detail; // turns out, this sometimes works better as expected...
      scrollTo = e.originalEvent.detail;
  }

  if (scrollTo > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

**[Here you have a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqaaqmzc/)**

Comment: i made the experience that `scrollTo = 20 * e.originalEvent.detail;` needs a little adjustment, I dont know anymore why I multiply it with 20 :)

Comment: you can however take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel and adjust it to your needs

Comment: You forgot the touch events. But your answer is pretty cool.

Comment: Thank you Alex, you helped me to solve this problem. I finally did it in [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639865/disable-scroll-down-with-jquery/25641204#25641204)

Answer (score 1):

Following Alex's answer, I managed to do it in the next way:

```
$(window).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel MozMousePixelScroll', function(e) {
    var direction = 0;
    if (e.type == 'mousewheel') {
        direction = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);
    } else if (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll') {
        direction = e.originalEvent.detail;
    }
    var divHeight = $("#myDiv").height();
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (direction > 0 && scrollTop > divHeight - window.innerHeight) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```